# How to distinct presets from AWS transcoding job if all providing same quality?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am transcoding a video from any format to HLS formats using AWS Elastic transcoding service. I am using five presets in single job for adaptive bit rate.

If video is of high input quality then video transcodes in different outputs qualities like 224p,270p, 360p,540p,720p.

But if video is of low input quality then video transcodes in different output qualities like 224p,270p, 360p,360p,360p. For low input quality there is three similar output quality i.e. 360p,360p,360p which is unnecessary cost of transcoding. How to avoid two presets for output quality 360p from AWS elastic transcoding job? Want to generate only output quality like 224p, 270p, 360p.

Comment: How you do the transcoding, I mean using batch process or pipeline.

Comment: @Bhavdip sagar : using pipeline

Answer (score 1):

You could use Lambda and mediainfo/ffmpeg to determine the resolution of the source and drop the file into a seperate bucket/pipeline for the appropriate encoding stack.

Though it may be overkill, [here's an example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/extracting-video-metadata-using-lambda-and-mediainfo/) of using mediainfo on lambda to extract and store the data in dynamo.